# How to differentiate alt text from figcaption

Tags: html

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this question, but there seems to be no consensus, even among blind users. I would appreciate help clarifying.

Suppose you have a figure with an image and a figcaption. What text should go in the image's alt attribute, and what text should go inside the figcaption. I understand that figcaption is visible to everyone, whereas alt text isn't, but that doesn't really point to an answer.

Let's say we have an image of a sunset. Should one try to be as descriptive as possible in the alt text, e.g., "A beautiful sunset viewed through a small round window", and be only general in the figcaption, e.g., "A beautiful sunset" ?

It seems clear to me that one shouldn't write the same thing for both alt text and figcaption since a screen reader will just read it twice the same way. I've also heard people say that it's bad to leave alt text empty even when there's a figcaption. What is regarded as best practice?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML

Comment: @MisterJojo I read through this, and it does a good job of explaining how to use the img alt attribute, but it doesn't have much to say about how to use them in combination with figcaptions. There's one example where it shows a long description in the figcaption and a short description in the img's alt attribute. Is that meant to imply that alt attributes should be concise and figcaptions should be as detailed as possible? It seemed unclear.

Comment: **alt**(alt property basically use when your image not visible for some reason Like server is down or the image path is incorrect then your alt property work as an **alternative** option of your image) And figcaption is like when everything working fine and your figure image is showing your figcaption will also visible to everyone.
this link clear you doubt
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp#:~:text=The%20required%20alt%20attribute%20specifies,user%20uses%20a%20screen%20reader).

Comment: @SagarKumar I know what both of them do, that wasn't my question. My question is what to do when the text is going to be the same for both. Do you leave alt empty because figcaption will be read by screen readers anyway? Do you write the same thing in both? Do you write one of them in a more descriptive way than the other?

Comment: read screen readers information also. I feel like I'm dealing with a bad chatbot.

Comment: No, because alt is basically used for image placeholder. For example, if you are setting a profile picture so your image is  `<figure>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="avatar" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 Profile Picture</figcaption>
</figure>` @ILikeThePoopSmith

Comment: @MisterJojo Not sure why you feel that way when the link you provided has nothing to say about my question.

Answer (score 0):

The intensity or vigor for your question is something that brings me to my post. When you see social media meta tags they are all custom, maybe this type of thing is something people have not conquered logically yet, and if they have is the standard generic or unique to the brand?

Even a standard may not be a reflection of what you want, and from what I'm assuming it's something for a text reader.

Me personally, while I'm waiting for the description I would really enjoy a path that leads me to it, not a repetitive structure that is helpful with visual acuity.

Those are my ten cents. I hope it helps and makes you believe people do care about things like that.